# how can I replace text in 10000 lines

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have over 10000 of such files and I am trying to make them as a template

my strings are like this

```
"MLKT_3C_AAAU_01A" 
"MLKT_3C_AALI_01A"
"MLKT_3C_AALJ_01A" 
"MLKT_3C_AALK_01A"
"MLKT_4H_AAAK_01A"
```

I am trying to convert them to this

```
names(MLKT_3C_AAAU_01A)[2] <- '3C_AAAU_01A' df<- full_join(df,MLKT_CS_4942_01A, by = 'V1')
names(MLKT_3C_AALI_01A)[2] <- '3C_AALI_01A' df<- full_join(df,MLKT_3C_AALI_01A, by = 'V1')
names(MLKT_3C_AALJ_01A)[2] <- '3C_AALJ_01A' df<- full_join(df,MLKT_3C_AALJ_01A, by = 'V1')
names(MLKT_3C_AALK_01A)[2] <- '3C_AALK_01A' df<- full_join(df,MLKT_3C_AALK_01A, by = 'V1')
names(MLKT_4H_AAAK_01A)[2] <- '4H_AAAK_01A' df<- full_join(df,MLKT_4H_AAAK_01A, by = 'V1')
```

The best way I came across until now was to use a text editor and make them one by one. I am wondering if there is a way in bash to get the above strings and convert it to the example I provided ?

before I start, I remove quotation from each line

```
sed 's/\"//g' example.txt > exampleout.txt
```

AT first I try to add `names(` at the beging of each line . so lets imagine my file which has all those strings per line is called exampleout.txt. which gives me three time names( instead once

```
awk '$0="names("$0' exampleout.txt > myout.txt
```

Then I try to paste `)[2] <- '' df<- full_join(df,, by = 'V1')` at the end of each line using the following

```
sed -e 's/$/)[2] <- '' df<- full_join(df,, by = 'V1') /' myout.txt > myout2.txt
```

so it led me to this

```
names(MLKT_3C_AAAU_01A )[2] <-  df<- full_join(df,, by = V1) 
names(MLKT_3C_AALI_01A)[2] <-  df<- full_join(df,, by = V1) 
names(MLKT_3C_AALJ_01A )[2] <-  df<- full_join(df,, by = V1) 
names(MLKT_3C_AALK_01A)[2] <-  df<- full_join(df,, by = V1) 
names(MLKT_4H_AAAK_01A)[2] <-  df<- full_join(df,, by = V1)
```

Comment: Did you make an attempt of your own? What tools have you considered?

Comment: @Learner, IMHO, even your attempts failed or not right its always recommended to add them in your post as we all are here to learn from each other. Request you to add them in your post and let us know then.

Comment: @ Inian I added all what I could do with bash :-)

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I added all what I could do with bash :-)

Comment: @Learner: `awk`/`sed` is not `bash`

Comment: @Inian I want to do it in anyway, I don't mind the way

Comment: For your first case, where did `MLKT_CS_4942_01A` come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ awk -F'"' '{
    x=$2; sub(/^[^_]+_/,"",x)
    printf "names(%s)[2] <- \047%s\047 df<- full_join(df,%s, by = \047V1\047)\n", $2, x, $2
}' file
names(MLKT_3C_AAAU_01A)[2] <- '3C_AAAU_01A' df<- full_join(df,MLKT_3C_AAAU_01A, by = 'V1')
names(MLKT_3C_AALI_01A)[2] <- '3C_AALI_01A' df<- full_join(df,MLKT_3C_AALI_01A, by = 'V1')
names(MLKT_3C_AALJ_01A)[2] <- '3C_AALJ_01A' df<- full_join(df,MLKT_3C_AALJ_01A, by = 'V1')
names(MLKT_3C_AALK_01A)[2] <- '3C_AALK_01A' df<- full_join(df,MLKT_3C_AALK_01A, by = 'V1')
names(MLKT_4H_AAAK_01A)[2] <- '4H_AAAK_01A' df<- full_join(df,MLKT_4H_AAAK_01A, by = 'V1')
```

Comment: I accepted your answer because it is simple . however, I would appreciate you put a time and explain it a bit , thanks a lot

Comment: I think it's extremely obvious what it's doing so not useful to explain - do you have any specific parts you dopn't understand that you have a question about?

Comment: Only this part, how did you get the expression figured ? `x=$2; sub(/^[^_]+_/,"",x)`

Comment: would it be possible somehow to break the output to next line before `df` ?, so the output looks like this `names(MLKT_3C_AAAU_01A)[2] <- '3C_AAAU_01A' 
df<- full_join(df,MLKT_3C_AAAU_01A, by = 'V1')
names(MLKT_3C_AALI_01A)[2] <- '3C_AALI_01A' 
df<- full_join(df,MLKT_3C_AALI_01A, by = 'V1')
names(MLKT_3C_AALJ_01A)[2] <- '3C_AALJ_01A' 
df<- full_join(df,MLKT_3C_AALJ_01A, by = 'V1')
names(MLKT_3C_AALK_01A)[2] <- '3C_AALK_01A' 
df<- full_join(df,MLKT_3C_AALK_01A, by = 'V1')
names(MLKT_4H_AAAK_01A)[2] <- '4H_AAAK_01A' 
df<- full_join(df,MLKT_4H_AAAK_01A, by = 'V1')`

Comment: q1) not sure what you mean, I'm just saving the input text in a variable and then removing everything up to the first `_` from it. q2) anything's possible but you can't put formatted code in a comment so idk what it is you're asking for. If you want a newline in the output just put `\n` in the output string wherever it is you want it - for example if you want to change `foo df` to `foo<newline>df` then just change the code to print `foo\ndf` instead of `foo df`.

Answer (score 3):

You can actually do it all in one command. The script below is similar to `sed`, only I've chosen to use `perl` to exploit non-greedy matching (`.*?_(.*)`) to separate the first underscored field.

```
perl -pe "s/^\"(.*?_(.*))\"$/names(\1)[2] <- '\2' df <- full_join(df, \1, by 'V1')/" example.txt
```

Here, I've captured two strings.

1. Everything inside the double-quotes, and
2. Everything after the first underscore.

For instance, in `"MLKT_3C_AAAU_01A"`, the first capture would be `MLKT_3C_AAAU_01A` and the second capture would be `3C_AAAU_01A`.

Afterwards, the appropriate substitutions are made.

---

If the field preceding the first underscore is a constant (e.g. `MLKT`), you could use `sed`, replacing the non-greedy match with the constant.

```
sed -E "s/^\"(MLKT_(.*))\"$/names(\1)[2] <- '\2' df <- full_join(df, \1, by 'V1')/" test.txt
```

Note the use of the `-E` flag (for extended regexes/easier group-capturing) and the use of double quotes (for using single-quotes as part of the replacement).

Comment: I liked your answer , THANKS a lot

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following.

```
awk -v s1="'" '
match($0,/[a-zA-Z][^"]*/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  split(val,array,"_")
  print "names(" val"[2] <- " s1 array[2]"_"array[3]"_"array[4] s1 " df<- full_join(df," val", by = " s1 "V1" s1")"
}'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
names(MLKT_3C_AAAU_01A[2] <- '3C_AAAU_01A' df<- full_join(df,MLKT_3C_AAAU_01A, by = 'V1')
names(MLKT_3C_AALI_01A[2] <- '3C_AALI_01A' df<- full_join(df,MLKT_3C_AALI_01A, by = 'V1')
names(MLKT_3C_AALJ_01A[2] <- '3C_AALJ_01A' df<- full_join(df,MLKT_3C_AALJ_01A, by = 'V1')
names(MLKT_3C_AALK_01A[2] <- '3C_AALK_01A' df<- full_join(df,MLKT_3C_AALK_01A, by = 'V1')
names(MLKT_4H_AAAK_01A[2] <- '4H_AAAK_01A' df<- full_join(df,MLKT_4H_AAAK_01A, by = 'V1')
```

Comment: I liked your answer , THANKS a lot

Answer (score 2):

Replacing a regex match with something is easily done with `sed`.

```
sed 's/^"\(MLKT_\([^"]*\)\)"$/things with \1 and even \2 in it/' file >newfile
```

The expression `\1` in the replacement text corresponds to the first parenthesized group in the regular expression, and `\2` corresponds to the second.  So if you matched `MLKT_1234` then `\1` will be the entire string, and `\2` will be `1234`.

If you need single quotes in the replacement, you have to unwrap them somehow.  Perhaps the simplest mechanic replacement is to express each literal single quote as `'\''` which is a closing single quote for the single-quoted string you are in, then a literal unquoted but backslashed single quote, and then an opening single quote to continue single-quoting the text which follows.

For any nontrivial replacements, though, perhaps you want to investigate Awk, which is somewhat more human-readable.

```
awk '{ # replace double quotes with nothing
    sub(/^"/, ""); sub(/"$/, "");
    # Now you can use $0 to refer to the remaining string
    # You can replace single quotes with \047
    print "names(" $0 ")[2] <- \047" \
        substr($0, 6) "\047 df<- full_join(df," \
        randomstring ", by = \047V1\047)" }' file >newfile
```

If `randomstring` comes from a second file, there's a common Awk pattern for joining values from two files (google for `NR==FNR`).